# Obtain data from Json using angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Below is my code:

post.json

```
[
    {
        "client_id":"100",
        "client_name":"MM Hope House",
        "user_fname":"Betty",
        "user_lname":"Johnson",
        "user_id":"10",
        "username":"bjohnson",
        "total_web":"$500",
        "campaigns":{
            "campaign":[{
                "id":"23",
                "campaign_name":"MM Hope House",
                "start_date":"4/15/2015",
                "end_date":"6/13/2015",
                "goal":"$20,000",
                "total_pledges":"$1550",
                "total_donations":"$1000"
            }],
            "pledgees":[{
                "pledgee_fname":"Tavonia",
                "pledgee_lname":"Evans",
                "pledge_email":"tavonia@gmail.com",
                "pledge_date":"4/22/2015",
                "pledge_amount":"$50.00",
                "paid":"$50.00",
                "last_pledge":"$50.00"
            }],
            "donors":[{
                "donor_fname":"Pat",
                "donor_lname":"Smith",
                "donor_email":"patsmith@onlinemediainteractive.com",
                "total_cdonation":"$10.00",
                "total_ldonation":"$450.00",
                "last_donation":"$200.00",
                "last_pledge":"$350.00"
            }]
        }
    }
]
```

My HTML code:

```
<script>

    function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http) {

        $http({method: 'POST', url: 'assets/js/posts.json'})
            .success(function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 $scope.posts = data;
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                 $scope.posts = data || "Request failed";
            });
    }

</script>
```

My HTML code where I want to populate data:

```
<thead>


<tr>
    <th>Campaign ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Email ID.</th>
    <th>Pledge Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="post in posts" >
    <td>{{post.id}}</td>
    <td>{{post.pledgee_fname}}</td>
    <td>{{post.pledgee_lname}}</td>
    <td>{{post.pledge_amount}}</td>
    <td>{{post.pledge_email}}</td>
    <td>{{post.pledge_date}}</td>
```

I am trying to get `client_id pleg_fname` from array, but do not know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pledgess` object is an array of objects so you should do this instead and your entire JSON is contained within an array so you need the first element which will be your entire object and you call it with `posts[0]` and then you specify the object you are trying to iterate : `pledgees`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="post in posts[0].campaigns.pledgees" >
  <td>{{posts[0].campaigns.campaign[0].id}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledgee_fname}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledgee_lname}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledge_amount}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledge_email}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledge_date}}</td>
```

**Edit**

You're right, I totally missed that array. See this plunker where I tested it http://plnkr.co/edit/dvdnjv2mN2gljQGI9Lls?p=preview

**Edit 2**

If you want the campaign ID just add this (updated the original code with this change)

```
{{posts[0].campaigns.campaign[0].id}}
```

Comment: have you seen this also campaigns all other arrays contain this one

Comment: You're right, I missed that array. See my updated answer.

Comment: but how i will get campaign id

Comment: but how i will get campaign_id <td>{{post.id}}</td>

Answer (score 1):

Because of your posts object contains **an array of one element**, you should use `posts[0]` to get the first (and the only one) element. Moreover, your **pledgees array is inside a campaigns object**, so `posts[0]` become `posts[0].compaigns.pledgees`.

You should try this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="post in posts[0].campaigns.pledgees" >
  <td>{{post.id}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledgee_fname}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledgee_lname}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledge_amount}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledge_email}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledge_date}}</td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT:**

And, if you want the **id from the campagin object** at the same index than your pledgee item, you have to add `track by $index` to `posts[0].campaigns.pledgees`. So it's become `posts[0].campaigns.pledgees track by $index`.

So, now with $index you get the right index to get the right campaign ID in the campaign object with `{{posts[0].campaigns.campaign[$index].id}}`

And the result is :

```
<tr ng-repeat="post in posts[0].campaigns.pledgees track by $index" >
  <td>{{posts[0].campaigns.campaign[$index].id}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledgee_fname}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledgee_lname}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledge_amount}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledge_email}}</td>
  <td>{{post.pledge_date}}</td>
</tr>
```

You can see the result here : http://jsfiddle.net/Fieldset/y1asxm61/1/

Comment: nope i am trying to populate data from json ...i am getting data correct but in case of array i don't know how i get it

Comment: The title is : "I want to GET data FROM Json using angular"

Comment: post.id is getting from campaign how i can get this also

Comment: Look my original post, edited. With this solution it get the right index (the same for pledgee)

Comment: You're welcome ! :) i edited my post to clear my answer